# Laravel Controller if else

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to make the function "take money from referral" in Controller if the condition is met. I have a widget that displays the amount of money earned from referrals and the button "add to account" below. My code is:

```
   if($ref_money < 320) {
        return [
            'msg'       => 'You need 320 coins on balance to take money',
             'type'      => 'error'
        ];
    } else {
        return [
        'title'       => 'You take '.$this->user->ref_money.' for refferals',
        'success' => true,
        ];
    }
```

If I have less than 320 on my balance (as it is written in the condition) and I press the "pick up" button, I received error `You need 320 coins on balance to take money`, but the money is added to my balance as a result. Why is that? After all, the condition is, if less than 320, then do not add, and if more, then add.

**EDIT:**

My full code of the function:

```
public function ref_money()
{
    $userid = $this->user->id;
    $user = User::where('id', $userid)->first();
    $ref_money = $user->ref_money;

    User::where('id', $user->id)->update([
        'money' => $user->money + $ref_money,
        'ref_money' => $user->ref_money - $ref_money
    ]);

    if($ref_money == 0) {
        return [
            'msg'       => 'You don\'t money have refferals',
            'type'      => 'error'
        ];
    }

   if($ref_money < 320) {
        return [
            'msg'       => 'You need 320 coins on balance to take money',
             'type'      => 'error'
        ];
    } else {
        return [
        'title'       => 'You take '.$this->user->ref_money.' for refferals',
        'success' => true,
        ];
    }   
}
```

Comment: This question cannot be answered with the code you posted since it doesnt have the logic youre talking about.

Comment: @Flame, i edit qustion and post full function code

Comment: move update function inside the else statement before the return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code:

```
public function ref_money()
{
    $userid = $this->user->id;
    $user = User::where('id', $userid)->first();
    $ref_money = $user->ref_money;

    if($ref_money == 0) {
        return [
            'msg'       => 'You don\'t money have refferals',
            'type'      => 'error'
        ];
    }

   if($ref_money < 320) {
        return [
            'msg'       => 'You need 320 coins on balance to take money',
             'type'      => 'error'
        ];
    } else {

        User::where('id', $user->id)->update([
            'money' => $user->money + $ref_money,
            'ref_money' => $user->ref_money - $ref_money
        ]);

        return [
        'title'       => 'You take '.$this->user->ref_money.' for refferals',
        'success' => true,
        ];
    }   
}
```

You were actually updating the money without any check, actually you need to do it only if ref_money is equals to or greater than 320.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
    public function ref_money()
{
    $userid = $this->user->id;
    $user = User::where('id', $userid)->first();
    $ref_money = $user->ref_money;

    if($ref_money == 0) {
        return [
            'msg'       => 'You don\'t money have refferals',
            'type'      => 'error'
        ];
    }

   if($ref_money < 320) {
        return [
            'msg'       => 'You need 320 coins on balance to take money',
             'type'      => 'error'
        ];
    } else {
  User::where('id', $user->id)->update([
        'money' => $user->money + $ref_money,
        'ref_money' => $user->ref_money - $ref_money
    ]);
        return [
        'title'       => 'You take '.$this->user->ref_money.' for refferals',
        'success' => true,
        ];
    }   
}
```